# Is it possible to show the number of pre-orders on the product page?

Tags: bigcommerce

My primary business is pre-orders, and this is how it works:

1. I list an item for sale.
2. My customers order the item. Their credit card is authorized but not charged.
3. Once a minimum number of orders are placed, the customers are charged, and the buy is live.
4. If, after a specified amount of time, the minimum is not reached, all orders are cancelled.

What i would like to do is this:

1. Specify the minimum number of orders needed for a particular item in the backend. (not 100% needed, but it would be nice).
2. Display the total number of pre-orders on the product page, so that my customers know how many are left before the buy is live (it would be great to show it in the following format: 23/50 Ordered).

Does anyone know if this is possible? If so, can you please explain to me what I need to do in order to make this happen?

Thanks!

P.S. - In case it doesn't show up, I'm using Bigcommerce

Answer (score 1):

Store the minimum needed as a custom field & set the initial inventory to that same number.  You'll also need to allow inventory to be displayed for pre-orders, though you can hide it from display if you'd like (we only want it present in the DOM).

As the products are pre-ordered, inventory will decrement.  Use javascript to subtract the number left in inventory from the original number (the custom field) and display in the ProductDetails.html panel.